# React Testing Library - Global configuration

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to override default testID attribute in React Testing Library. Using Jest as a testing framework.

For this, I have followed the steps given [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-configuration/) at individual test file level.

Is there any way to have this configuration at global (project) level, so that all the test files in the project will adhere to such custom configuration and will not have need to define custom configuration explicitly at test file level?

Comment: Are you using jest ? Can you post your general testing configuration file ?

Comment: Yes using Jest. Updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using jest you can add the following in file

```
import { configure } from 'react-testing-library';

configure({
  testIdAttribute: 'data-my-test-id',
});
```

and include that file in the `jest.config.js` file in the `setupFiles` property

```
setupFiles: [
  '<rootDir>/path-to-your-configuration-file.js',
]
```

Comment: Im trying to do the above but i get an error when i run my test: `{import {configure} from 'react-testing-library';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score -1):

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-configuration/#introduction

```
import {configure} from '@testing-library/dom'

configure({
  testIdAttribute: 'data-my-test-id',
  
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).